# String created with concatenating non ascii chars produces garbage while sending it as text message

Tags: java, android, string, character-encoding, sms

I have the following piece of code :

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, 
        msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString() + "ławka", null, null);
```

While changing `ł` to `l` I can send the message successfully without problem but when I use `ł` I get garbage in my message.

I have tried following with the same effect :

```
    message = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString() + " ławka";
    byte b[] = null;
    try {
      b = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
      SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
      smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, new String(b, "UTF-8"), null, null);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**EDIT**

I have also tried this :

```
Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
message = String.format(l, "%s %s", msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString() ,"ławka");
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the SMS PDU the payload is 7bit ascii for text.  Unicode, 16 bit, is a type of data message.   I don't know this SmsManager but I think you will need to send unicode messages as Data.